# How to optimize parallel computing in PyTorch (GPU)

Tags: algorithm, pytorch, parallel-processing

I am trying to solve the initial value problem of a system of ordinary differential equations using torchdiff. The input y0 of the forward function is a one-dimensional tensor with a size of 120000. In the function, it is first sliced into 12 one-dimensional tensors with a length of 10000: A, B, C... L. In addition, there are several coefficients q1, q2, q3... which are forced to use a large number of torch. cat operations during parallel computing, resulting in low GPU utilization. Is there a way to optimize algorithms to improve computational speed?
What I did was as follows:

```
N_SP = 10000
zeros_mat = torch.zeros(N_SP)
def forward(self, t, y0, rates, ba_input):
    k1, \
    k2, k3, k4\
    k5, k6... = rates

    A = y0[0:N_sp]  
    B = y0[N_sp:2 * N_sp]  
    C = y0[2 * N_sp:3 * N_sp]  
    D = y0[3 * N_sp:4 * N_sp] 
    E = y0[4 * N_sp:5 * N_sp]  
    F = y0[5 * N_sp:6 * N_sp]  
    G = y0[6 * N_sp:7 * N_sp]  
    H = y0[7 * N_sp:8 * N_sp]  
    I = y0[8 * N_sp:9 * N_sp]  
    J = y0[9 * N_sp:10 * N_sp]  
    K = y0[10 * N_sp:11 * N_sp]  
    L = y0[11 * N_sp:12 * N_sp]  

    y1 = torch.cat((k1*A,k5*B,k5*B,k2*D,k7*G,k4*G,zeros_mat,zeros_mat,zeros_mat,k2*H,k3*I,k4*J),0) *torch.cat((L,L,L,L,L,L,zeros_mat,zeros_mat,zeros_mat,K,K,L)) + \
 torch.cat((k7*D,k4*A,K4*J,K6*B,K3*B,K2*E,K3*A,K6*H,K9*I,K3*H,torch.ones(N_sp),ba_input),0)+\
torch.cat((zeros_mat,zeros_mat,zeros_mat,zeros_mat,zeros_mat,zeros_mat,zeros_mat,zeros_mat,zeros_mat,zeros_mat,L**4,L**4),0)*\
torch.cat((zeros_mat,zeros_mat,zeros_mat,zeros_mat,zeros_mat,zeros_mat,zeros_mat,zeros_mat,zeros_mat,zeros_mat,H,H),0)*

return = y1
```

This is a system of ordinary differential equations solved using the odeint function of the Torchdiff library, which has high coupling. If there is no need for tensor splicing, the GPU utilization rate can reach nearly 100%.

In addition, I have also attempted to initialize a global tensor array externally to fill the required "blocks" through slicing operations instead of concatenation operations. The effect is not good.

Comment: Additional explanation: k1, k2, k3... are coefficients.If anyone can answer, I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: The relevant variables have been moved to the GPU. Additionally, the coefficient expression is incorrect, not q1, q2, q3..., but k1, k2, k3.